# torch.no_grad() and detach() combined

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch, gradient-descent

I encountered many code fragments like the following for choosing an action, that include a mix of `torch.no_grad` and `detach` (where `actor` is some actor, `SomeDistribution` your preferred distribution), and I'm wondering whether they make sense:

```
def f():
    with torch.no_grad():
        x = actor(observation)
    dist = SomeDistribution(x)
    sample = dist.sample()
    return sample.detach()
```

Is the use of `detach` in the return statement not unnecessary, as x has its `requires_grad` already set to False, so all computations using `x` should already be detached from the graph? Or do the computations after the `torch.no_grad` wrapper somehow end up on the graph again, so we need to detach them once again in the end (in which case it seems to me that `no_grad` would be unnecessary)?
Also, if I'm right, I suppose instead of omitting `detach` one could also omit `torch.no_grad`, and end up with the same functionality, but worse performance, so `torch.no_grad` is to be preferred?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it may be redundant, it depends on the internals of `actor` and `SomeDistribution`. In general, there are three cases I can think of where `detach` would be necessary in this code. Since you've already observed that `x` has `requires_grad` set to `False` then cases 2 and 3 don't apply to your specific case.

1. If `SomeDistribution` has internal parameters (leaf tensors with `requires_grad=True`) then `dist.sample()` may result in a computation graph connecting `sample` to those parameters. Without detaching, that computation graph, including those parameters, would be unnecessarily kept in memory after returning.
2. The default behavior within a `torch.no_grad` context is to return the result of tensor operations having `requires_grad` set to `False`. However, if `actor(observation)` for some reason explicitly sets `requires_grad` of its return value to `True` before returning, then a computation graph may be created that connects `x` to `sample`. Without detaching, that computation graph, including `x`, would be unnecessarily kept in memory after returning.
3. This one seems even more unlikely, but if `actor(observation)` actually just returns a reference to `observation`, and `observation.requires_grad` is `True`, then a computation graph all the way from `observation` to `sample` may be constructed during `dist.sample()`.

As for the suggestion of removing the `no_grad` context in leu of `detach`, this may result in the construction of a computation graph connecting `observation` (if it requires gradients) and/or the parameters of the distribution (if it has any) to `x`. The graph would be discarded after `detach`, but it does take time and memory to create the computation graph, so there may be a performance penalty.

In conclusion, it's safer to do both `no_grad` and `detach`, though the necessity of either depends on the details of the distribution and actor.

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth response! I suppose I could've added some more details. `actor` is a simple feed-forward NN that turns `observation` into a scalar and does not do anything weird like setting `requires_grad`. `SomeDistribution` is a 'normal' torch distribution, usually `Categorical` from `torch.distributions`. So this should eliminate cases 2 and 3, and probably also 1? So in my case, `detach` seems to be unnecessary, but it doesn't hurt to include it? Either way, the worst that can really happen if I don't use it is that it might hurt performance, but not functionality, correct?

Comment: Yeah in your case it's probably unnecessary to detach, tho its not going to hurt to have it. Keeping it there alleviates the performance concern, and since it costs basically nothing to run detach on a tensor it makes sense to keep it imo. It also helps future proof the code a bit, in case someone decides to use a more exotic distribution down the line.

Comment: Yes I'll do that. I also wasn't aware `detach` is that cheap to run, but with that in mind I suppose there's no reason not to use it. Thanks for your help!